# New name of a paper doesn't show up in Google

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

Around one month ago I changed the name of one paper of mine on ArXiv. I noticed that on google scholar it still appear with the old name and that if I search on google with the new name it does not find anything.

Is there a workaround to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.  This is probably not a question we can answer,

Comment: @BobBrown do you mean that this question is not related to Academia community?

Comment: @Krebto Sometimes Google is just a black box and there's no way to know what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Google Scholar account?

If so, visit the page "My Profile", click on the title of the corresponding article. You can edit (click the "pen" button) the title there to match the updated arXiv title.

If not, I am not sure there is anything you can do.

EDIT: I did have the same issue at one point. After waiting for a few months I tried the manual editing and it worked. When users click on your article, they'll see the different versions of the paper.

Comment: If I modify the title manually it will remove the link of the arxiv paper from google scholar

Comment: Is the original paper still appearing as another entry?